# Loop SQlite3 database continuously, when query found run script for first 3

Tags: linux, bash, sqlite, loops, watch

I have a SQlite database gets populated when ever someone adds a filename and dir to it, then I want the script to read the newest 3 entries (done with the "LIMIT 3") then I want this script to take those 3 entries and start the "script1.sh" for each of them, then once the script1 has finished one of the 3, I want it to look back into the SQlite database and check if there are any new entires and repeat. (so kinda like a queue) 
NOTE, at the end of script1.sh there is a command that will delete it's entry from the SQlite DB.

So basically I want the script to check the SQlite DB each time one script1.sh script finishes.

So far I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlite3 /database.db  "SELECT * FROM main ORDER BY mKey ASC LIMIT 3" | while read file
do
fileName=`echo "$file" | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[2]}'`
echo "$fileName"

    #Run script
    ./script1.sh "$fileName" "$file"


done
```

Comment: What should the script do if there is nothing new?

Comment: Just keep checking the DB ever 5 seconds. 
Of if possible, some kind of watch command to just wait till something new comes.

Comment: Unfortunately what you want is really pushing the limit of what bash can do. As you know, I took a crack at it below with only partial results. The problems are (1) the sqlite3 shell command does not return errors. (2) bash doesn't have a good way to wait for the *next* process to exit, it can only wait for a specific one or all of them. That's annoying, because the raw system call *does* just wait for the next. The script could trap SIGCHLD (and so get control as each child exits) but I was worried about race conditions while doing shell arithmetic in a signal handler.

Comment: The short version of the story is that this should probably be done in a real language.  I would suggest Ruby, but any real language with an sqlite3 API can do it. Ask another question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

key=0
while :; do
  sqlite3 -column ./test.db \
   "SELECT * FROM main WHERE mKey > $key ORDER BY mKey ASC LIMIT 3" > tmpFile
  lastKey=$key
  while read k f; do
      key=$k
      echo start script1 on $f here current key is $k
  done < tmpFile
  [ $key -eq $lastKey ] && sleep 1
done
```

I wasn't sure you really wanted the newest 3, since you also said you wanted a queue, so I got the *next* 3 each time, starting with the first.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is half of what I need, I also needed it to run the 3 concurrently, not one after another.
Will see what I can make out of this.

Comment: BTW, my prototype script was tested on an sqlite3 database with the following schema: `CREATE TABLE main (mKey INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, pathName);`

Comment: Cheers.
Ended up not using this method, seemed way to complicated.

Just using your infinite while loop, and then using sqlite3 to do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `echo` and `awk`, Bash can do that for you:

```
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS='|'
fileName=(${file})        # make an array
fileName=${fileName[2]}   # get an element
IFS=$saveIFS              # put it back like you found it
```

You are missing a "`done`", by the way.